# Order of factors for unit/counit of duals

Tags: ct.category-theory, duality

While working through [Categorical quantum mechanics](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0808.1023.pdf) by Abramsky and Coecke, I noticed that their definition of the order of factors for the unit and counit of a dualizable object disagree with the one at the [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dualizable+object). They cite the 1980 Kelly and Laplaza [paper](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/0022404980901012?token=E2D3A17A6B366C5E25CB04C90FE67F4A42564880071F136F0E0A47FF5282D363081C75B3BA2738E8EF521AB30501C350&originRegion=us-east-1&originCreation=20211007061034) on compact closed categories for their definition, but this paper defines the order of the factors the same way the nlab does. They seem to use their ordering for the remainder of the paper (i.e. defining $f^*$), which makes me wonder

> What impact does the order of factors have on the contents of their paper? Is there a reason they chose to reverse the ordering?

Right off the bat we end up with the fact that the counit doesn't technically embed the complex numbers on the diagonal of a matrix, and that bra-ket notation looks backwards. Are there any more serious one?

Comment: What do you mean by "order of factors"?

Comment: The ordering of the tensor product of the object with its dual in the definition of the unit/counit arrows for dual objects.

Comment: We are in a *symmetric* monoidal category, right?  So the order doesn't really matter...

Comment: @MikeShulman Yes, it just seemed an odd choice and I've got pages of notes with the ordering in the other direction. (if there's no consequential difference I'll just leave the notes alone)

Answer (score 2):

Just to air out some thoughts here:

- The thing I reach for when deciding the order to write here is this: Let $X$ be an object and $[X , I]$ its internal hom *to* the unit. Note that $X = [I, X]$ is the same as the internal hom *from* the unit. If $X$ is dualizable, then it's natural to write the counit of the dualizability data so that it agrees with the evaluation map.
- But how do we write the evaluation map? The evalutation map is an internalization of composition. So the way you write the evaluation map is going to depend on whether you're writing composition in *diagrammatic* order, or in *op-diagrammatic* (or "conventional") order.

I think I tend to instinctively write the counit as $X \otimes [X , I] \to I$ because I'm thinking of it as evaluation written in *diagrammatic* order. Probably the reason this is backwards from Dirac's bra-ket notation is that bra-ket corresponds to thinking of evaluation as written in *op-diagrammatic* order -- the order you get when you write $g(f(x)) = (g \circ f)(x)$.

So this is another case where there might be a distinction to be drawn between *the order that you write things on paper* and *the order of "priority"*. Some people -- such as [reverse Poles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) write in op-diagrammatic order $(g \circ f)(x) = f(g(x))$. Are they using a different notion of composition, or rather the same notion of composition written differently? I'm not sure!

The discussion of "chirality" in 1.1.4 - 1.1.5 of Berrick and Keating's *Rings and Categories of Modules* seems relevant here. It would be nice if we had better ways of talking about this sort of issue -- maybe Berrick and Keating's terminology should be more widely adopted!